# on click event on list item not having any response or console output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I am trying to make an accordion with my list.

```js
'use strict'

$(document).ready(function() {

  var drops = $('.accords');

  drops.on('click', function() {
    console.log(drops.length);
    for (i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
      $(this).toggleClass('acc');

      if ($(this).hasClass('acc')) {
        $(this).children('.accordion').css({
          'max-height': '500px'
        });
      } else {
        $(this).children('.accordion').css({
          'max-height': '0'
        });
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 148px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  padding: 17px 0 13px;
  max-height: 124px;
  background-color: $black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .logo {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-mini {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 45px;
    li {
      padding-bottom: 45px;
      display: inline;
      padding-right: 20px;
      &:last-child {
        padding-right: 0;
      }
    }
    a {
      font-size: 14px;
      &:hover {
        background-color: $white;
        color: $black;
      }
    }
  }
  @include breakpoint (tablet) {
    .nav-desktop {
      display: none;
    }
    .nav-mini {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}

.nav-mini {
  padding-top: 26px !important;
  .mini-menu {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    padding: 9px 15.5px;
  }
  .mini-search {
    float: right;
    padding: 9px 14px;
  }
  .mini-menu,
  .mini-search {
    border: 2px solid $white;
  }
}

.dropdown-mini {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 124px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: $white;
}

.lvl-one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 33px !important;
  a {
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }
  li {
    display: block !important;
    padding: 17.5px 0 !important;
    border-top: 3px solid $black;
    font-family: $f-bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    &:last-child {
      border-bottom: 3px solid $black;
    }
    span {
      float: right;
      padding-right: 6px;
    }
    .accordion {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      .row {
        padding-top: 24px;
        .txt {
          font-size: 14px;
          word-spacing: 0em;
          line-height: 26px;
          margin-top: -6px;
          width: 99%;
          padding-bottom: 26px;
          .orange {
            float: none !important;
          }
        }
        h4 {
          letter-spacing: -0.09em !important;
          padding-bottom: 3px;
        }
        h5 {
          font-size: 13px !important;
          word-spacing: -0.2em !important;
        }
      }
      ul {
        li {
          border: none;
          padding: 7.5px 0 !important;
          font-size: 14px !important;
          &:first-child {
            padding-top: 0 !important;
          }
          &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
          }
          a {
            font-size: 14px !important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.drop {
  height: 480px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 123px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
  left: 0;
  .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    .dropdown {
      display: none;
      height: 480px;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: $white;
      top: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
}

.drop-cont {
  padding: 56px 100px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.drop-links {
  margin-right: 130px;
  width: 470px;
  li {
    padding: 15.5px 0;
    &:first-child {
      padding-top: 30px;
    }
    &:last-child {
      padding-bottom: 35px;
    }
  }
  a {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

.drop-txt {
  float: right;
  max-width: 370px;
  .txt {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 59px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    letter-spacing: -0.03em;
    line-height: 1.7;
    .orange {
      font-size: 19px;
    }
  }
  .sub {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
  }
  h5 {
    font-size: 13px;
    word-spacing: -0.2em;
  }
}

.drop-links,
.drop-txt {
  border-top: 3px solid $black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid $black;
}

.dropped {
  background-color: $white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="dropdown-mini">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="nav lvl-one">
          <ul>
            <li class="accords"><a href="javascript:;" class="black ">ABOUT US</a><span>v</span>
              <div class="accordion">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col col-2-t">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="accord"><a href="javascript:;">INTRODUCTION<span></span></a></li>
                      <li class="accord"><a href="javascript:;">VISION & VALUES<span></span></a></li>
                      <li class="accord"><a href="javascript:;">OUR STRATEGY<span></span></a></li>
                      <li class="accord"><a href="javascript:;">BUSINESS MODEL<span></span></a></li>
                      <li class="accord"><a href="javascript:;">LEADERSHIP TEAM<span></span></a></li>
                      <li class="accord"><a href="javascript:;">GOVERNANCE<span></span></a></li>
                      <li class="accord"><a href="javascript:;">HISTORY<span></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col col-2-t">
                    <p class="txt black">
                      <span class="orange">“</span>In blandit porta consequat. Phasellus orci diam, laoreet in tristique pellentesque, sodales ut diam. Maecenas et quam quis erat accumsan iaculis ac vitae dolor. Cras mattis tellus condimentum pharetra
                      fermentum. Nulla porta risus id odio varius. <span class="orange">“</span>
                    </p>
                    <h4 class="sub">TERRY THAM</h4>
                    <h5>Managing Director</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="black portfolio">OUR PORTFOLIO</a><span>v</span></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="black">INVESTORS</a><span>v</span></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="black">NEWS & MEDIA</a><span>v</span></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="black">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/y92j0thc/11/)

The part that I can't make work is the `.on(click)` function. When I click on the **ABOUT US** list element , the `.accordion` should get some max height (should be visible). But as you see, I tried testing the code after the click event happens. In console I get nothing. Not sure why. Does it matter if the clickable item has to be a `<li>` ?

Not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: That jsfiddle throws error `$ is not defined` - it misses jQuery

Comment: I changed it ... shoud be ok now

Comment: Anyway it's better to put code in your question instead of relying on 3rd part links

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question
but hope this help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click','href',function(){
   if($(this).attr("href")==="#"){
     return false;
    }
  });
 $(".about-span").click(function(){
   $(".about-div").slideToggle();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
header{
  padding:10px;
  background-color:teal;
}
a{
  color:#fff;
}
ul{
  padding:0;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:2px;
}
.about-div{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:teal;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
}
.about-li{
  display:block;
  padding:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="about-span"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></span>
          <div class="about-div">
            <ul>
              <li class="about-li"><a href="#">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
              <li class="about-li"><a href="#">VISION & VALUES</a></li>
              <li class="about-li"><a href="#">OUR STRATEGY</a></li>
              <li class="about-li"><a href="#">BUSINESS MODEL</a></li>
              <li class="about-li"><a href="#">LEADERSHIP TEAM</a></li>
              <li class="about-li"><a href="#">GOVERNANCE</a></li>
              <li class="about-li"><a href="#">HISTORY</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OUR PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INVESTORS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS & MEDIA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
  </header>

</body>
```

Comment: why is there return false ?

Comment: I tried doing it with similar code to yours but it didn't do much.. `var drops = $('.accords');

  $(document).on('click', drops , function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('acc');

    if($(this).hasClass('acc')) {
      $(this).children('.accordion').css({'display':'block'});
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $(this).children('.accordion').css({'display':'none'});
    }
    
  })`

Comment: Actually , now my classes are being added on click ! Great . Im still not getting `.accordion` to drop on click tho. but hey its a progress ! :D

Comment: return false is just for href="#", this will not change hash

Comment: ah i see , This gave me a hint so i will try to change my code a bit ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In JSFiddle you can't just use JQuery by default. You have to select the library.
Click on `JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS)` and select your library which would be `JQuery 3.3.1` in your case.

Then you will find the output in the Browser Console.

Edit:
Btw you got another error. `i is not defined`. To solve this you just need to type `var i;` for example below the `var drops = ...` line.

Here is a fiddle with JQuery selected and all errors solved.
https://jsfiddle.net/y92j0thc/6/

Comment: changed it .. should be ok now